# Referencing a Library file stored on TFS

Tags: c#, dll, tfs

I have created a Reference Library (DLL) that contains testing utilities for use by multiple users. The Library is stored on our TFS so that all users can contribute to it and gain access to it. However, it seems that the only way for each user to reference the library is to create a copy of the library on their local machine and make the reference to that location. Whenever anyone makes changes to this library, the user then must make a new copy of the file onto their local machine. In my mind, this seems silly. Is there a way that each user can reference the library within TFS itself, rather than having to create a new copy of it each time there are changes made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create it as a NuGet package. If you search around SO for sharing code between solutions, that will be the advice. TFS is not a network drive.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on this? I'm new to VS and TFS